# C#: Checking Remote Machine Port Status

Tags: c#, server, port, tcpclient

**How do I write a C# program to check if a port is open in a remote machine from a server?**

- i.e access the server first and then check if a port is open/closed
  in another machine from there
- I'm aware of the  new TcpClient(hostname, port) command; but do not know how to do that from a server.

Comment: This is related to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11837541/check-if-a-port-is-open

Comment: Yes .But I have to first login to a server(Machine A) and check the port status of another remote machine (Machine B) . I know how to do it directly for  Machine B.

Comment: hmm I think not without a program that listens your commands on server side. Think that this can be a very dangerous exploit. the most thing you can do is to use the Ping class but that's not what you need.

Comment: I was asked to model it on the  PSEXEC.exe