# RDP at the TCP level

Tags: c#, rdp

I'm looking for a library that would allow me to communicate with a remote computer via the RDP protocol, but without windows. I don't need control. In fact, I only need to check the availability of multiple servers via RDP.

So far I've seen: 1. ActiveX component with wrapper. But it requires a window, which is logical. But it doesn't suit me. 2. Watched the specification of the protocol. It's not easy there. Lots of structures. For everything, it seems there is a description and you may have to do with it.

Comment: *"I only need to check the availability of multiple servers via RDP"* can't you just [ping the port](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11837541/check-if-a-port-is-open) to see if the machine is up or not?

Comment: you need to check the validity of the username and password

Comment: maybe there is something new and simpler?

Comment: seems like you should look up some existing solutions of cheaking the hearbeat of the servers , its a basic functionality, and there is plenty, not really scope of stack overflow TBH

Comment: is there any example in the code?